# Is this DJango code snippet correctly retrieving data from the database?

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, debugging

I am having some issues with DJango. Currently, our website does not display all the options in the drop-down menu. It just shows one element that is not appropriate, see image.
[image]

My suspicion is that the JQuery is not correctly retrieving the data. I was taking a look at the HTML file, and at line 42 is where the DJango code loops through the entity books, in order to retrieve the book id attribute that we want to display in the drop-down menu. I am new to DJango, and I am not sure if those lines(42-45) are correctly executing. Thank you very much. 
[image]

Comment: The templating says "create an option for each `book` in the `books` variable". It means that on the server/Django side, there is a `books` variable that is holding all your books. If you believe some books are missing, you need to look at how this variable gets its values. It is likely done in a `views.py` file.

Comment: There could be only one book present in the books list that is sent from django to the frontend or there is probably only one book in the database itself. This needs to be checked in django code

Comment: Either there's only one book or the book e is replaced each and every time and so you end up with only one option

Comment: Paste your code here instead of using pictures, that way is easier to help by copying and modifying your code for an answer. Also post your view to see how are you passing the books to the context.